# Let $Q$ be a symmetric $n$ by $n$ matrix, there exists an orthogonal matrix $F$ such that $F^TQF=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $Q$ be a symmetric $n$ by $n$ square matrix, there exists an orthogonal matrix $F$ such that $$F^TQF=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n),$$ with $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ being its eigenvalues.

I know little about linear algebra, but I hope somebody could help me prove it because I'm studying differential geometry

Comment: this is in every linear algebra/matrix theory book on earth  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_diagonalization

Comment: I'm quite surprised you're studying differential geometry without prior knowledge of linear algebra.

Comment: Not know little.it's a little bit actually

Answer (score 0):

This is known as Sylvester's Law of Inertia (more or less). This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia) refers to Sylvester's original proof, so you could read that. There are, of course, more modern treatments around. :)